# When does a double become NaN?

Tags: c#, nan, standard-deviation

I am trying to understand which circumstances can cause a double to become NaN.

For instance, 0/0 is nan. This is also stated in the official Documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.nan?view=net-6.0

However, my debug code indicates that the division is not by 0:

```
public class StandardDeviation
{
    public StandardDeviation()
    {
        Clear();
    }
    private double M { get; set; }
    private double S { get; set; }
    private uint Iteration { get; set; }
    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(S / (Iteration - 2));
        }

    }
    public void AddValue(double value)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("value IS nan!");
        }
        double tmpM = M;
        M += (value - tmpM) / Iteration;
        S += (value - tmpM) * (value - M);
        Iteration++;
        if (double.IsNaN(M))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nNAN EXCEPTION!!! divide by: {Iteration}");
Console.WriteLine($"\nNAN EXCEPTION!!! tmpM: {tmpM}");
            throw new ArgumentException("m IS nan!");
        }
    }
    public void Clear()
    {
        M = 0.0;
        S = 0.0;
        Iteration = 1;
    }
}
```

console message:

```
NAN EXCEPTION!!! divide by: 3
NAN EXCEPTION!!! tmpM: ∞
```

The issue primairly seems to be prevalent in release configuration, which makes it hard to debug.

Whenever the exception is thrown, Iteration = 3.

Comment: Could you also include `tmpM` in the Console.WriteLine?

Comment: alright, value is ∞. How do i check for that? double.IsPositiveInfinity?

Comment: @alp I use a random generator for testing

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN

Comment: maybe consider checking double.IsNormal - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.isnormal?view=net-6.0 - and deny any operation on non normal values

Comment: If Iteration is 3, you are in the second iteration (because of the ++ before), so if tmpM is now infinite, M must have been set to infinite already in the first iteration. Except of course some code modified the properties or StandardDeviation in between.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help and suggestions! I think I will settle with double.IsNormal for now. The Documentation of `double.isnormal` seems more than lacking!